# Quick SELECT sometimes time out

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have stored procedure which execute simple select. Any time I run it manually, it runs under the second. But in production (SQL Azure S2 database) it runs inside scheduled task every 12 ours - so I think it is reasonable to expect it to run every time with "cold" - with no cached data. And the performance is very unpredictable - sometimes it takes 5 second, sometimes 30 and sometimes even 100.

The select is optimized to the maximum (of my knowledge, anyway) - I created filtered index including all the columns returned from SELECT, so the only operation in execution plan is Index scan. There is huge difference between estimated and actual rows:

[image]

But overall the query seems pretty lightweight. I do not blame environment (SQL Azure) because there is A LOT of queries executing all the time, and this one is the only one with this performance problem.

Here is XML execution plan for SQL ninjas willing to help : http://pastebin.com/u5GCz0vW

EDIT:

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [myproject].[Purchase](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ProductId] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [DeviceId] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
    [Receipt] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [AppVersion] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [OSType] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [IP] [nchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ValidationState] [smallint] NOT NULL,
    [ValidationInfo] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ValidationError] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [ValidatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [PurchaseId] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [PurchaseDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ExpirationDate] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Purchase] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)
```

Index definition:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AndroidRevalidationTargets3] ON [myproject].[Purchase]
(
    [ExpirationDate] ASC,
    [ValidatedOn] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [ProductId],
    [DeviceId],
    [UserId],
    [Receipt],
    [AppVersion],
    [OSType],
    [IP],
    [CreatedOn],
    [ValidationState],
    [ValidationInfo],
    [ValidationError],
    [PurchaseId],
    [PurchaseDate]) 
WHERE ([OSType]=(1) AND [ProductId] IS NOT NULL AND [ProductId]<>'trial' AND ([ValidationState] IN ((1), (0), (-2))))
```

Data can be considered sensitive, so I cant provide sample.

Comment: could you please provide table structure, query and sample data? thx

Comment: just adeed table and index definition. Query is in execution plan. Cant provide sample data, since they are sensitive.

Comment: How many rows are in that index and how big is it in MB? All of those must be scanned.

Comment: When I make select count(*) on the table with the same WHERE clause that filtered index has, I got 22000, so I guess that is the row count of the index as well.

Comment: sample data does not mean orignal data - just a few records to get an idea of what is stored in this table!

Comment: There are many variants. Another long-running query may be locking your table. Outdated statistics may lead to generation of poor execution plan. Parameter sniffing may lead to re-using of non-optimal plan as parameter value changes. Index scan is not seek, so it has to read the whole index. Big difference in estimated and actual number of rows suggest that statistics is out of date. Are there a lot of frequent inserts/updates on this table? It should not take even 5 seconds to read 22K rows - maybe there are a lot of waits.

Comment: Yes, there are frequent inserts and less frequent updates on the table. But there are no other long-running queries, nor am I using any locks etc. What can I do to make statistics accurate?

Comment: Estimated data size `672MB`. It is quite a lot for 22K rows. You must have got large `nvarchar(max)`. Each `INSERT/UPDATE` has to change your index (because all columns are included). Since index is so big it takes time. While index is being updated, it is locked, so reading query waits. I would remove all `included` columns from the index. And monitor what else is running while your `select` query runs.

Comment: BTW, creating a `filtered` index makes sense when the filter eliminates significant amount of rows from the index and makes it smaller. If your table has 1M rows and filtered index 22K - it is good. If your table has 25K rows and index 22K - not so good.

Comment: That 672MB is size of index? Also, I dont understand those 50k estimated rows, when index have only 22k. Yes, the table is pretty big, currently about 2 millions rows, so filter to 22K is pretty good I think.

Comment: The estimated data size is determined by ridiculously crude query optimizer heuristics, meaningless. Tell us, as requested, the actual size of the index. How many rows are in the index? Not rows that survive the filter but rows in the index. Use the index properties to find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your query returns only 1 match, I think you should trim down your index to a bare minimum. You can get the remaining columns via a Key Lookup from the clustered index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AndroidRevalidationTargets3] ON [myproject].[Purchase]
(
    [ExpirationDate] ASC,
    [ValidatedOn] ASC
)
WHERE ([OSType]=(1) AND [ProductId] IS NOT NULL AND [ProductId]<>'trial' AND ([ValidationState] IN ((1), (0), (-2))))
```

This doesn't eliminate the scan, but it makes the index much leaner for a fast read.

**Edit:** OP stated that the slimmed-down index was ignored by SQL Server. You can force SQL Server to use the filter index:

```
SELECT *
FROM [myproject].[Purchase] WITH (INDEX(IX_AndroidRevalidationTargets3))
```

Comment: As far as I know, I cant include ExpirationDate into where clause on my filtered index, for the paramter expirationTimeTo changes from call to call.

Comment: As for your solution, I tried it before I included the columns into index, and just to be sure I tried it again now - the index you suggest will not be used. Execution plan will be just one heavy Clustered Index Scan, and the query takes 3 minues. Any idea why the engine will not use the index if it doesnt have columns included?

Comment: Actually I think I know why - estimated number of rows is about 50000, so I guess DB thinks it is better to just scan the cluster index... but actual number of rows is again 1-2

Comment: You can force SQL Server to use the filtering index: `FROM [myproject].[Purchase] WITH (INDEX(IX_AndroidRevalidationTargets3))`. May be it's not seeing the connection between your query and the filter on the index. You are right, the condition on `ExpirationDate` cannot be put on the index.

Comment: Hmm.. didnt thought of that. OK, I have modified my stored procedure to force the new slim index without included columns. It runs blazing fast now - but I think everything is cached by now :) Gonna let it run by scheduler in few hours, we will see. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like your solution with explitictly forcing this index in stored procedure select did the trick - last few executions (every 12 hours) were all under 1 sec. Please edit your answer and I will gladly accept it (dont forget to remove the first part about expiration date :)